# google clouds billing not working with prepaid card

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm new to using google clouds with payment. and i've been trying to add my payment info. and i've added my card number , MM/YY and cvv. but when i try to submit this info it prompts an error

`Unable to complete transaction: prepaid cards can't be used` .

i tried to contact my provider but they say it's not the card issue. i'm also using the card on different platforms like amazon and netflix.

why isn't it not working on Google cloud?

Comment: Contact (join) a Google Developer group in your area. They might have a program that you can opt into [link](https://developers.google.com/community/gdg).

Comment: @JohnHanley I've tried to contact google support but they never gave me an answer

Comment: Did you join a local group or did you send them a `help me` email? They are not technical support. They are a group that helps developers.

Comment: @JohnHanley i've contacted google support, coz i think my issue is that my country is not supported

Comment: No, your payment method is not supported.

Comment: @JohnHanley i think so b/c it only accepts cards that are related to banks or that can be verified

Comment: The primary features that a debit/credit offer that a prepaid card does not have are: a) Identity Verification; b) Recurring Payments. Google requires both.

Comment: Questions regarding billing and payment are off-topic except if you use APIs and write code.

Comment: @JohnHanley my card used to ask me verification before but it didn't work, this was about a month ago. and now it just don't even work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Google official docs](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods?visit_id=638200831968383837-189708354&rd=1#unsupported_payment_methods), ***Prepaid cards and Virtual Credit Cards (VCCs) are not accepted for payment by Google***.

> Instead  The [payment methods available](https://support.google.com/paymentscenter/answer/9001356?ref_topic=9023854#allowed-methods) for your self-serve
> (online) Cloud Billing account depends on your [currency and
> country](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/currency). In many countries, you can set up a credit card, debit
> card, or bank account as a primary payment method.

Referring to this [supported payment methods](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods?visit_id=638200831968383837-189708354&rd=1#supported_payment_methods) for Google cloud billing, will help you to pay the google cloud bill and You can also contact [Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) for help.

Comment: the supported link you provided is unreachable

Comment: I'm only using this type of payment method is b/c that's the only way i can have international payment method. i'm from Ethiopia so is there any way i can make the payment that's supported?

Comment: @MohammedBekele : I have edited the link  and added cloud billing support link now and have a check to the process given in it.

Comment: @MohammedBekele : Can you check this [Payment Options in my country](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/2380700?hl=en) check for your country and click on the payment method link given beside to it and follow the process.

Comment: I'm in Africa and the there are only South Africa and others option but i live in Ethiopia. so maybe it's others for me and in others it supports credit/debit card. mine is a debit master card.

Comment: Can you try using the debit master card let me know the error and also follow this [What if my country isn't listed when I try to add my billing address?](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1229455?sjid=4889565083678908225-AP&visit_id=638200898679192756-3823246118&rd=1#zippy=%2Cwhat-if-my-country-isnt-listed-when-i-try-to-add-my-billing-address). Transfer your account to one of our Google Partners who might be able to change your billing account's country for you. Find a [Google Partner](https://cloud.google.com/find-a-partner/?location=ethiopia) for Ethiopia location.

Comment: i've asked for the only partner in Ethiopia and they've said they only support google workspace. is there a way that i can have offline payment. by making advanced deposit and making usage from that

Comment: @MohammedBekele : Can you contact a [Google Sales representative](https://workspace.google.com/contact-form/) to discuss options, `such as paying by check` and in you country i can see [applythings](https://cloud.google.com/find-a-partner/partner/appythings) one of the `partner providing the support Google Cloud Platform`.

Comment: I have the same problem in the UK with my business debit card. It's not a pre-paid card yet Google's validation seems to think it is.